# Why are my logic gates are exploding in TinkerCad?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image]

Why is this happening in my logic gates?

Comment: David Ordoñez - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules here differ from typical forums. (b) Please [edit] your question to add the *schematic*, since it's difficult for readers to reverse-engineer that wiring diagram to understand what your actual design is. (c) Please also add some context - what are you making and is it your design or are you copying it from somewhere else? If it comes from elsewhere, please add a link to that source. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a user of TinkerCad but find the the ``breadboard`` diagram difficult to analyse. Can you follow the information in [Is there a schematic view of my Tinkercad circuit?](https://www.tinkercad.com/help/circuits/schematic-view-of-circuit) and edit the question to include the _schematic view_. Just displaying that may show the issue, e.g. might show that two logic gate outputs are shorted together.

Comment: Are the 165 mA the real current you have? DIL switches as drawn? LED is on or off? Anyway from the datasheet [74HC00](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/74HC00-105628.pdf) and [74HC04](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74HC04.pdf) you should have around 50 mA here! Every DIP switch on is 15 mA/off 0 uA, LED on 5 mA/off 0 uA, all ICs less than 1 mA! There is nothing in your circuit that should oscillate - except the [contact bouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) shortly at switching on/off the DIP switch.

Comment: @BitLauncher - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. FYI I have removed 2 of your comments since (a) they were effectively giving a multi-post answer (which is not an [allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)); and (b) now you've posted that answer (thanks), the comments duplicate that answer, so they're not needed anyway.

Comment: Tinkercad is flagging a serious error with the exploding component symbol. Is there a way to see what the error is? Maybe hover on the exploding symbol. Floating inputs could be flagged as an issue, but why aren't more ICs flagged?

Comment: The full version of TinkerCad should have a "Schematic View" tool button. Can you use that to convert the 3D design into a  schematic view? Then post that here instead. It seems that you have at least a few open inputs, these are difficult to diagnose in the 3D view. Also notice that your power supply current shows 165 mA, that high a current suggests that there are serious problems.

Comment: On a Q&A you simply ask the question, not whether anyone knows X. Also show thanks by voting on and accepting answers.

Answer (score 3):

You have a gate driving into ground when switch 3 is closed, follow the red dots. The simulator flags this as a serious error with an exploding symbol.

Since this is a static CMOS circuit, unless the LED is on, it should draw way less than a milliamp.

*BitLauncher* has a lot of good comments if you are building a real circuit. Decouplers can be really important, but I would doubt that this simulator has enough fidelity to notice the lack of decouplers.

In the simulator, I don't know if floating inputs (that don't propagate into your logic) will be an issue or not. Certainly, if I am building a real circuit, I always connect all CMOS inputs.

[image]

FYI: A real logic IC won't explode if you short an output. It may be damaged by overheating, depends on the logic family. Now if you connect an IC to a stiff power supply reversed, I have seen ICs literally explode.

Answer (score 0):

If I think over all comments from others and me, fix it by:

0. getting the schematic and post it here. ;-)

a) connect all unused input pins to either GND or 5V (here it does not matter)
(so 74HC00 pins 1,2,4,5,9,10,12,13 if not used, and for 74HC04 pins 1,3,5,9,11,13 - due to floating input voltage, you operate the IC outside of its specification. And the 74HC family has an input current of nothing - 0.1 uA max, so even worse - finally the IC could oscillate, consume more power, or even burn (but this is not directly the case for your leftest IC, that explodes - because all input pins of leftest IC are connected to somewhere)

b) connect a 100 nF ceramic! capacitor as short as possible between pin 7 and 14 of each IC - this reduces power supply voltage drops at an IC that switches its output (low to high, high to low), especially the 74HC family is fast (ca. 15 ns switching time) and has quite powerfull outputs.

In your breadboard the rightest 2 ICs have floating input pins - so they can oscillate "randomly" and produce spikes in supply current and drops of the power voltage.
And because the 3 leftest ICs are connected afterwards, their supply voltage is noisy, full of voltage drop glitches. Or if the leftest produce supply current spikes the voltage drops on all ICs to their right and left!
This fast change of power supply voltage can cause unintended switching of an output... until an oscillation at around probably up to roughly 60 MHz could happen (15 ns switching time).
Or more severe: this oscillation provokes input signals that are neither low nor high, therefore the ICs are operated in a forbidden zone - overheating can be expected.

The points a) and b) could fix it already. But there is some more improvement possibilities:

c) The 5V for the ICs is taken from upper breadboard plus row and the GND is taken from the lower minus breadboard row - and the power supply's 5V is also connected to upper plus row and GND to lower minus row.
This produces a huge loop for supply current. Especially the power supply spikes from switching in the ICs can produce magnetic fields - and you have very long connections on your breadboard - there could be unintented signal coupling. This can be solved by connecting the power supply GND and 5V both to the upper breadboard row minus and plus. And connecting each IC directly to the upper breadboard row minus and plus! Like that you can even place the ceramic capacitors from b) near the 2 tapping points for the IC's power supply.
Here your connections could be harmful because the 74HC family is fast and have a strong output driving capability (20 mA).

d) The DIP switches make [contact bouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) - and with a parasite capacitance of ca. 2 pF to each neighbor column of a breadboard - 4 pF with 330 = 1.2 ns time constant should not be a problem - if a) and b) are done! But like this, it could provoke a burst of power supply current spikes and voltage drops, that amplify the problems of unsolved a) and b). Best use a debouncing circuit - here I propose to connect the dip switch pins to schmitt trigger input pins like the 74HC14 or 74HC132 - use a higher pull up resistor of e. g. 10k and capacitors from the pin to GND of ca. 100 nF or higher --> contact bounces still happens, but switching/bouncing cannot happen faster than every 1 ms roughly.

PS: Another solution is: Use a slow digital logic family (4000er) with lower output drive capabilities (and perhaps schmitt trigger inputs) like 40106 and 4093 - then a) is needed, b) is good practice - and it works. Your schematic has nothing to do with fast switching time - it is a "static" logic with the dip switches. You would need just a stronger driver for the LED (perhaps).